# Create new instance of WCF client on closing timeout?

Tags: c#, wcf, timeout

I have a class for creating my WCF service client.

Is it possible to create new instance whenever service is time out? I mean each time out, closing, opening, receiving. But Closing is more important for me.

As the following:

```
public class ServiceClientFactory
{
    private static SmartServiceClient _client;
    internal SmartServiceClient Client
    {
        get
        {
            if (_client is not closed && _client != null) return _client;
            _client = new SmartServiceClient();
            return _client;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code appears to create a client for calling a service, not the service itself

Comment: @TomRedfern: You're right. I want it actually, I edited title

Comment: FYI just editted my answer to simplify code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to modify your factory code - you also need to check for the [Faulted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.communicationstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) state:

```
if (_client != null) 
{
    if (_client.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
    {
        _client.Abort(); // Use when channel is faulted
    }

    // Now you can check for closed state etc...
    else if (_client.State != CommunicationState.Closed)
    {
        return _client;
    }
}

_client = new SmartServiceClient();
return _client;
```

If there was a timeout exception the channel will be in faulted state, so the next time you try to get your client...

```
var client = ServiceClientFactory.Client; // Client is renewed here.
```

...you will get a new instance.